# Large Gap on content in mj-table

Tags: html-email, css-tables, mjml

I'm using a table to hold the content of a mailshot I'm working, I'm doing so because I'm trying to maintain a newspaper-esque style. However under the '11 November at 6pm' head on the right hand side, there is a large gap that I'm struggling to remove. Anyone got any ideas on how I can rectify this?

Example is here: [**Example**](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/HJkBF9YOw)

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: I think you need to add `vertical-align:top` to the td, but can't figure out how to in the syntax. Neither inline CSS nor a separate attribute (`vertical-align="top"`) appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears one needs to add more content in to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vertical-align:top` to the `<td>` style.

i.e. `<td style="padding: 15px 0 0;vertical-align:top" width="50%">`

There appears to be a bug in the MJML live preview that removes it, however, if you click 'Minify HTML' and copy *that* code, it preserves it.

[image: Screenshot on Apple Mail showing top-aligned text]